# TypeError: insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I've spent the better part of a hour just trying to find the solution to this error: TypeError: insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string' ...
Someone please help D:
Here is a small piece of code that I wrote. And yea I am very new to python and tkinter.. Probably just a noob mistake..

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")
message = Entry(root, width=10).grid(row=1, column=1)
message = Entry.insert(message, "default")

root.mainloop()
```

And here is the error that i keep getting:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Hidden\DoS\_console.py", line 6, in <module>
    message = Entry.insert(message, "default")
TypeError: insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'
```

Comment: Also can you set the default text on a Text widget? If so how would you go about that. I would be using 'Text' the same way as 'Entry'..

Comment: `message = Entry.insert(message, "default")` - what? Why are you calling this method on the `Entry` class itself? Why are you passing `message` as an argument or assigning the result to `message`? How did you even come up with this line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the definition of [`insert`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.insert-method) method:

> `insert(index, string)`
>   Inserts text at the given index. Use `insert(INSERT, text)` to insert text at the cursor, `insert(END, text)` to append text to the widget.

I think you need to use it like this:

```
message = Entry(root, width=10).grid(row=1, column=1)
message.insert(INSERT, "default")
```

I used `INSERT` to insert the text at cursor position.

If you need to add it in the start:

```
message.insert(0, "default")
```

Comment: That's great. Please do follow this post: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers